# 7zip - Encrypting and compressing each file in a folder while maintaining directory structure

Tags: windows, command-line, encryption, compression, 7-zip

Say I have a directory structure like this:

```
- main folder
  - folder 1
     - file 1.txt
  - folder 2
  - folder 3
     - file 2.txt
     - file 3.png
  - file 4.txt
  - file 5.jpg
```

I'd like to create a batch script in Windows where I can drag/drop `main folder` onto it and it'll do the following:

```
- main folder_encrypted
  - folder 1
     - file 1.txt.7z
  - folder 2
  - folder 3
     - file 2.txt.7z
     - file 3.png.7z
  - file 4.txt.7z
  - file 5.jpg.7z
```

Basically, it'll maintain directory structure and individually compress and encrypt every file using 7zip and copy it to `main folder_encrypted`

Comment: Everything you need is in https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/ and http://ss64.com/nt/ ;)

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).